# Wait time for resetting Apple Id account

Tags: apple-id, password

Recently, I tried the account recovery process of AppleID, which I had logged in. I had forgotten the password, and the recovery option was the last resort. I tried resetting the password by using a friend's apple device. But, there was a wait time of 24 hours. I didn't get any communication from Apple regarding my account as of now.

After that, I rechecked the next morning and the wait period had reduced to 5 hours. I want to know if I can actually get my AppleID back because many people are complaining about Apple's horrible and useless recovery process. Also, what process do I need to follow after the wait time is over, (if I can get a heads up)?

> We are evaluating your information We are evaluating your information and will have an update in 5 hours. Apple Support cannot help to reduce your waiting period.
>
> When it is time to reset your password, we will send instructions to ••••••••52.

P.S - Apple hasn't sent any email or SMS stating that a request to change my password was done, etc.  I feel it's like a bad sign.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of Apple anti-fraud and anti-takeover, so you should expect to wait the full time since that’s designed into the system to allow the owner of the email to react to the request to reset that triggered the extra protection.

Next time, If you call into support you might get more guidance on the process or avoid having it go into a “need to check with the devices and emails” registered state.

When the time has passed you will have enough information to either complete the process assigned (we can’t guess the state your account is - only Apple Support can tell you that) or to advise you wait 3 more hours and then contact Apple support if you think the agreed time has passed.

Comment: My father is the owner. He forgot his account details. I had not made any purchases, because it was brand new, and I was setting up the device, where he had forgotten the password. I think they should at least ask for invoice copy to shorten the wait time, and expect to wait, if one cannot verify ownership, to satisfaction.